# Font not found on android with kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, label, buildozer

I am writing an app with kivy, and I have ran into a problem. I want to use standard but custom fonts in my app, I mean something like Arial or Calibri, this is my label code:

```
lbl = Label(text=str(font), on_press=callback, font_name="Arial", font_size="35sp")
```

while that works on Windows, on Android it doesn't! It says that Arial.ttf can't be found.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue copying the fonts inside the app folder, and editing the spec file to include all ttf files

Answer (score 0):

On Android (7.0 at least is what I have), there is a very limited set of fonts and none of the usual ones like Arial Calibri and so on are there. You can check with:

```
adb shell 'ls /system/fonts'
```

If you have a Samsung phone at least there is a mechanism for downloading some new fonts from the app store, but again that may not include the common truetype ones. That leaves manually installing fonts onto Android, which is best done with root permission or less easily with an app like zfont.